# VueJS Computed Calculation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently creating a small little calculator application with VueJS, and this is also my first experience with VueJS.

However I was wondering if I'm actually doing things correct, as I currently have the following code:

```
export default{
name:'app',
data(){
    return{
        form:{
            sitetype:"Standard",
            designChoices:"Template",
            speed:"Less than 1 month",
            pages:1,
            copywriting:"",
            features:[]
        },
        options:{
             sitetype:[
                {text:"Standard",         price:{low:800, high:1500}},
                {text:"E-Commerce",       price:{low:2000,high:4000}},
                {text:"Custom Production",price:{low:5000,high:8000}}
            ],
            designChoices:[
                {text:"Template",     price:{low:200, high:500}},
                {text:"Custom Design",price:{low:1200,high:2000}}
            ],
            speed:[
                {text:"Less than 1 month",   price:{low:1000,high:3000}},
                {text:"Around 1 to 2 months",price:{low:500, high:1000}},
                {text:"More than 2 months",  price:{low:250, high:500}}
            ],
            features:[
                {id:"seo",price:{low:250,high:500}, text:"Search Engine Optimisation (SEO)"},
                {id:"smo",price:{low:400,high:800}, text:"Social Media Optimisation (SMO)"},
                {id:"mail",price:{low:150,high:300}, text:"Mail Setup"},
                {id:"gallery",price:{low:250,high:500}, text:"Image/Sliders Gallery"},
            ]
        }
    }
},
computed:{
//Calculate Mimimum Price
    calcMin(){
        var featuresPrice = 0,
            priceIndex = 0,
            copywriting = this.form.copywriting == "Yes" ? 2.5 : 1;
        //Feature Loop
        this.form.features.forEach(feature=>{
            this.options.features.forEach(featureCheck=>{
                if(feature == featureCheck.text){
                    featuresPrice += featureCheck.price.low
                    priceIndex++;
                }
            });
        });
        //Calculate all the values!
        var minPrice = featuresPrice + ((this.form.pages * 50) * copywriting);
        return minPrice;
    },
    //Calculate Maximum Price
    calcMax(){
        return "To Be Filled";
    }
  }
}
```

This code is minimised compared to the full code example found on this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RafaelDeJongh/d8dmheL8/

Here I want to focus on the **computed** part. I use a loop inside a loop here to confirm my data and retrieve the prices from each of the features being 12 in total (but for this example only 4, the full functionality can be found on the jsfiddle).

So with the loop inside a loop I'm therefore confirming each part to make the price add up to itself, however I also need to do this for the other 3 components as well being 3 dropdown boxes (sitetype,designChoices,Speed).

Copying loops to get this effect is definitely not the right way to do it I think, so the real question here is: How would I properly utilise or change my code so that I can properly provide data as well as use prices linked to that data for my calculation?

Thanks in advance for further information.

Edit:

Now I'm a bit further and gotten this code for the calculation:

```
computed:{
//Calculate Mimimum Price
    calcMin(){
        var copywriting = this.form.copywriting == "Yes" ? 2.5 : 1;
        var otherPrice = 0;
        for(var option in this.options) {
            if ("features" == option) {
                var featuresPrice = this.form[option].reduce((total,current)=>{
                    var optionFeatures = this.options[option].filter(featureCheck => featureCheck.text == current);
                    optionFeatures.forEach(check=>{otherPrice += check.price.low});
                    return otherPrice;
                },0);
            }else{
                for(var index in this.options[option]){
                    if(this.options[option][index].text == this.form[option]){
                        otherPrice += this.options[option][index].price.low;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        //Calculate the price
        var minPrice = otherPrice + ((this.form.pages * 50) * copywriting);
        return minPrice;
    },
//Calculate Maximum Price
    calcMax(){
        var copywriting = this.form.copywriting == "Yes" ? 5 : 1;
        var otherPrice = 0;
        for(var option in this.options) {
            if ("features" == option) {
                var featuresPrice = this.form[option].reduce((total,current)=>{
                    var optionFeatures = this.options[option].filter(featureCheck => featureCheck.text == current);
                    optionFeatures.forEach(check=>{otherPrice += check.price.high});
                    return otherPrice;
                },0);
            }else{
                for(var index in this.options[option]) {
                    if(this.options[option][index].text == this.form[option]){
                        otherPrice += this.options[option][index].price.high;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        //Calculate the price
        var maxPrice = otherPrice + ((this.form.pages * 150) * copywriting);
        return maxPrice;
    },
}
```

My question here is, could it be written easier or more simplified as in, could I combine both calculations and only change a couple variables like the price.low/price.high and such? If so how would I perform this exactly?

Updated JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RafaelDeJongh/d8dmheL8/4/

Edit 2:

With some more work and research I now have the following code:

```
methods:{
    calcPrice(isMin){
    //Calculate CopyWriting
        var copywriting = this.form.copywriting == "Yes" ? (isMin ? 2.5 : 5) : 1;
        //Calculate Features
            var otherPrice = 0;
            for(var option in this.options){
                if ("features" == option){
                    var featuresPrice = this.form[option].reduce((total,current)=>{
                        var optionFeatures = this.options[option].filter(featureCheck => featureCheck.text == current);
                        optionFeatures.forEach(check=>{
                            otherPrice += isMin ? check.price.low : check.price.high;
                        });
                        return otherPrice;
                    },0);
                }else{
                //Calculate Options
                    for(var index in this.options[option]){
                    var getOption = this.options[option][index];
                        if(getOption.text == this.form[option]){
                            otherPrice += isMin ? getOption.price.low : getOption.price.high;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            //Calculate The Total Price + Pages
            var price = otherPrice + ((this.form.pages * (isMin ? 50 : 150)) * copywriting);
            return price;
    }
},
computed:{
    //Calculate Mimimum Price
    calcMin(){return this.calcPrice(true);},
    //Calculate Maximum Price
    calcMax(){return this.calcPrice(false);}
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RafaelDeJongh/d8dmheL8/5/

So I was wondering if this code could be further optimised or changed in anyway to make it better in terms of VueJS? Or would this code be acceptable?

Comment: you might want to turn the loops into a `method` which you can then call with an argument so you don't need to copy the looping part.

Comment: Good call, I currently have done it like following

`var featuresPrice = this.form.features.reduce((state,feature,index,array)=>{
    var optionFeatures = this.options.features.filter(featureCheck => featureCheck.text == feature);
    optionFeatures.forEach(check=>{
     state += check.price.low
    });
    var speedFeature = this.options.speed.filter(speedCheck => speedCheck.text == feature);
    speedFeature.forEach(speed=>{
     state += check.speed.low
    });
   return state;
   },0);`

But might indeed be better off with putting it into a method.
Any examples are welcome!

Comment: instead of doing `this.options.features` you could do `this.options[theFeature]` where `theFeature` is `speed`,`designChoices`, etc.  which would allow you to create a method to easily retrieve that stuff.

Comment: @A.Lau made some changes as what you suggested, any further suggestions are very welcomed!